# Why isn't the data rendered in sorted order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, use-effect, web-frontend

**Why isn't the rendered data in sorted order**

I am passing rides as a prop in the NearestRides component and inside the NearestRides component, first i am sorting the rides and setting to sortedRides and then i am mapping sortedRides.

but why is the sortedRides not sorted?

is sortedRides getting rendered before getting sorted? if so, how do i sort rides before rendering?

**Rides.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import NearestRides from "./NearestRides";

const Rides = () => {
  const [rides, setRides] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRides = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://assessment.api.vweb.app/rides');
      const json = await data.json();
      setRides(json);
    }

    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const data = await fetch('https://assessment.api.vweb.app/user');

      const json = await data.json();
      console.log(json);
      setUser(json);
    }
    
    const makeNetworkCalls = async() => {
      await fetchRides();
      await fetchUser();
    }

    makeNetworkCalls().catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    })

  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const calculateDistance = async(path, user_station) => {
      let min = Math.abs(user_station - path[0]);
      for(let i = 0; i<path.length; i++){
        if(path[i] === user_station){
          return 0;
        }
        if(Math.abs(path[i] - user_station) < min){
          min = Math.abs(path[i] - user_station);
        }
      }
      return min;
    }

    const updaterides = async () => {
      rides.map(async (ride) => {
        ride.distance = await calculateDistance(
          ride.station_path,
          user.station_code
        );
      });
    };

    if (rides?.length > 0) {
      updaterides().catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    }
  }, [rides,user]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar user = {user}/>
      <div className="home">
        <NearestRides rides = {rides}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}

export default Rides;
```

**NearestRides.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const NearestRides = ({rides}) => {
  const [sortedRides, setSortedRides] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const sortRides = async() => {
      const sorted = await rides.sort((ride1,ride2) => {
        return ride1.distance > ride2.distance ? 1 : -1;
      })

      setSortedRides(sorted);
    }

    sortRides().catch((e) => console.log(e));

  }, [rides]);

  return(
    <div className="rides">
      {console.log(sortedRides)}
      {sortedRides?.map((ride) => {
        return (
          <div className="ride-detail">
          <img src={ride.map_url} alt="Ride_map" />
          <div>
            <p>Ride Id : {ride.id}</p>
            <p>Origin Station : {ride.origin_station_code}</p>
            <p>Station Path : {ride.station_path}</p>
            <p>Date : {ride.date}</p>
            <p>Distance : {ride.distance}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default NearestRides;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that when you are calculating the `distance` and adding the distance property to rides array, you are not actually setting it again to the `rides` using `setRides`.

And so, the `distance` is never part of the `rides` array when received in child `nearestRides` and hence sorting method is not working in `nestedRides`.

But setting the rides in the useEffect with deps will create infinite loop.

So suggest to calculate the distance in the useEffect with no deps - ie right after you fetch the rides.

Comment: if that was the case then it would have given an error in NearestRides on accessing distance in the ride, and rides has the distance added

Comment: Do you already have distance in your rides array when you get from server with a default value? Also I would like to know when you console sortedRides, do you get distance in the objects?